# How to set exact length of Crystal report through code?

Tags: c#, printing, crystal-reports

I have a report designed in Crystal Rerports 12x8.5 inch. I have my OKI 3320 printer driver set exactly to this size. 
Now, when I print the report using my C# code, **the page length is half inch short of the tear off position. I have to roll up paper to tear it off.** Is there any settings we can change through code to exactly get to the tear off position?

```
          ReportDocument oReportDocument = new ReportDocument();
            oReportDocument.Load(reportPath + "\\OutDkt.rpt");

            List<TblOutDocket> lstDockets = new List<TblOutDocket>();
            lstDockets.Add(oTblOutDocket);
            oReportDocument.SetDataSource(lstDockets);

            oReportDocument.PrintOptions.PrinterName = LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue().FullName;
            oReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems when you are using custom page sizes you need to specify the page settings specifically. According to this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/vscrystalreports/thread/d000c32e-a3ea-4bb3-a110-bf1d51ed5212) you can achieve this by setting the PageSettings namespace.

> When you want to use a papersize with an id greater then 118 (Windows
> coded papersize) you must supply the id of your papersize to
> PrintOptions.PaperSource. Obviuosly you need to cast it at
> CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSource I do this:
>
> ReportDocument.PrintOptions.PaperSource =
> (CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSource)m_PageSettings.PaperSource.RawKind;
>
> ReportDocument.PrintOptions.PaperSize =
> (CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSize)m_PageSettings.PaperSize.RawKind;
>
> Where m_PageSettings is my System.Drawing.PageSettings that specify
> the right PaperSize